# Keep focus on desired tab in Salesforce Application

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference

I am having an application in which I have added one Tab in it also it has a default Home Tab.

Now I need to open up another visualforce page on a button click.

I have used PageReference here :

```
    public PageReference GoToMasterPage(){
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/MySecondPage');
        pr.setRedirect(true); 
        return pr;
}
```

whenever it gets executed it opens up correct VF page but, the focus always shifts to Home Tab which was present by default.

I do not want the focus to shift to the Home tab or any other tab. I it need to focus on the currently selected tab itself.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the new tab which you created is a **visual-force tab** than add `tabStyle` attribute in page tag in your `MySecondPage` page. So the page code would be like :

```
<apex: page tabStyle="TabName__tab">
   <!---page code-->
</apex:page>
```

If the tab related to **custom object** then:

```
<apex:page tabstyle="CustomObject__c">
  <!---page code-->
</apex:page>
```